# How can i insert a row using hibernate method?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am trying to insert a row into a relation table Stock Category.

I am following this example: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Now I already have data in table stock and category.

Later I want to associate a stock and category to each other.

How I can do this without writing a custom sql query?

Is it  possible if I can add StockCategory  like this?

```
Stock stock = new Stock();
stock.setStockId(1);
Category category = new Category();
category.setCategoryId(1);
StockCategory stockCategory = new StockCategory();

stockCategory.setStock(stock); //here you need to get the stock object by id 
stockCategory.setCategory(category1); //here you need to get the category1 object by id
stockCategory.setCreatedDate(new Date()); //extra column
stockCategory.setCreatedBy("system"); //extra column
session.save(stockCategory );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't it describe in the tutorial?

Comment: wait .I am checking the code

Comment: where are some fields like nullable = false.You need to set values to those

Answer (score 6):

```
StockCategory stockCategory = new StockCategory();

stockCategory.setStock(stock); //here you need to get the stock object by id
stockCategory.setCategory(category1); //here you need to get the category1 object by id
stockCategory.setCreatedDate(new Date()); //extra column
stockCategory.setCreatedBy("system"); //extra column
session.save(stock);
```

It is also there

Comment: If I have other fields of stock and category as null . Will it still works?

Comment: if you specified the fields are not null it will throw exception.If they are nullable no problem.

Comment: @Thinker Did not specified in the example as nullable = false.So by default they are nullable.So no problem for u

Comment: @Thinker did you understand now

Comment: No.You dint get my point. I have a new Stock having `id` as `11`. And new Category having id as `12`. Now these two link does not have a row in `stockcategory` table . Then I just want to insert a new row in `stockcategory` table.  I dont want to update user.

Comment: How i can fire a criteria query on StockCategory class?  `Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserResponse.class);
   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user_id", userId));`  This is giving me error.

Answer (score 2):

An ORM like Hibernate map Java objects to the datasource and create a model of this data, then you create and update the objects and call a save subroutine to update the model. The Insert/Update/Delete SQL commands are done by the ORM library.

So in the example of creating a new object, the datasource is not updated until  `session.save(stock)` is called.

```
   session.beginTransaction();

    Stock stock = new Stock();
    stock.setStockCode("7052");
    stock.setStockName("PADINI");

    //assume category id is 7
    Category category1 = (Category)session.get(Category.class, 7);

    StockCategory stockCategory = new StockCategory();
    stockCategory.setStock(stock);
    stockCategory.setCategory(category1);
    stockCategory.setCreatedDate(new Date()); //extra column
    stockCategory.setCreatedBy("system"); //extra column

    stock.getStockCategories().add(stockCategory);

    session.save(stock);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you define appropriate relationships, your code will work. 
For example - if your StockCategory.java looks something like this, then what you are doing will work.

```
Class StockCategory{

     @ManyToOne(...)
     private Stock stock;

     @ManyToOne(...)
     private Category category;
}
```

Then the following code will work. You don't have to populate other fields in Stock and Category.

```
    Stock stock = new Stock();
    stock.setStockId(1);
    Category category = new Category();
    category.setCategoryId(1);
    StockCategory stockCategory = new StockCategory();

    stockCategory.setStock(stock); 
    stockCategory.setCategory(category1); 
    stockCategory.setCreatedDate(new Date()); //extra column
    stockCategory.setCreatedBy("system"); //extra column
    session.save(stockCategory );
```